# printing arrays to text file (v2)

Tags: arrays, perl, printing

yesterday i asked this question and got many helpful replies, hoping the same will be true today. Here is my revised script.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line;
my @array;
my $print;

open (OUT , ">","output.txt")or die "cant open: $!"; 
while ($line  = <>){
        chomp($line);
        push(@array, $line);
        if(@array == 250){
        $print = print "[", join(",",@array), "]", "\n";
        print OUT $print;
        @array = []
}
}
```

Originally i simply stated that i need to print out the first 250 elements of an array to a text file, and that this array was built from standard input. What i didnt state is that the input, from which the array is built, may consist of several thousand lines. The reason for creating an array from this input is so that i can limit the size of the array to 250 entities, and then print the array as a formatted string. I then need to flush the array and resume building at what will become the 251st line of the input, and continue doing this process for the remainder of the input. Lets say the input is 5k lines, i want my output to be a text file containing the original 5k lines of input, but divided into strings made up of 250 array entities.

Currently the script is just printing the array to the screen and inside "ouput.txt" is a single line reading: `1111111`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$print = print "[", join(",",@array), "]", "\n";
print OUT $print;
```

Here you are assigning the return value of print to $print, which is 1, because the printing is successful. What you want to do is this:

```
print OUT "[", join(",",@array), "]", "\n";
```

Comment: Also `@array = []` is incorrect. It creates an array reference. It should be `@array = ()` or `undef @array`.

Comment: yes, wonderful. Now however im getting lines like this in my output file:

'[ARRAY(0x936cd0),'

Comment: sweet, that did it perfectly. Now how do i make it stop printing everything to the screen? i want it to only print to that .txt file.

Comment: it should not print to STDOUT any more..did you leave the '$print = print' statement there? comment it out!

Comment: @TedDorosheff: that's exactly what this answer tells you

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option which just slightly modifies your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array;
local $" = ',';

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    push @array, $_;

    if ( @array == 250 ) {
        print "[@array]\n";
        undef @array;
    }
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl Infile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

The variable `$"` is holds Perl's list separator that's applied to an interpolated array, so `join`'s not needed here.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line;
my @array;
my $print;

open (OUT , ">","moloch_chunker_output.txt")or die "cant open: $!";
while ($line  = <>){
        chomp($line);
        push(@array, $line);
        if(@array == 250){
        print OUT "[", join(",",@array), "]", "\n";
        @array = ();
}
}
```

Thank you davs, that fixed it.